# Export a number of reports, using different queries but same template

Tags: ms-access, vba

Good Afternoon,

I have around 10 queries that filter the same data set, and all have the same fields.

I have built a single report that shows this data, and can be exported to .PDF.

By changing the record source to the desired query, I am able to produce reports for all my queries, however this is time consuming. As it needs to be done every week it is not a viable option.

More importantly, the report design is likely to change over time. It would be possible for me to make 10 copies of the report, and then provide the correct query to each one, however this would mean any changes made to the report would have to be made 10 times over.

Does anyone know how I can use VBA / macros to automate this? The logic would be similar to the following.

1. Copy the template report
2. Change the Record Source to Query A
3. Export report as ReportA.pdf
4. Delete Report
5. Copy template report
6. Change the Record Source to Query B
   ...

And so on. It seems like this should be possible, I just don't know how to do step 1. and 2. and 3.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any of that. Simply have a single query with a single report with that query as a recordsource. The only criteria contained in the query should be what is common to all uses. Then you simply open the report with the desired filter.

`DoCmd.OpenReport <YourReportName>, acViewPreview, , <YourFilterCriteria>`

For exporting, set a tempvar to your filter criteria

`<YourTempVar> = <YourFilterCriteria> 
DoCmd.outputTo acOutputReport, <YourReportName>, acFormatPDF, <OutputFileName>`

In the open event of the report set the report's filter to the tempvar.

`Me.Filter = <YourTempVar>`

Comment: Hi, thanks you for the reply. I'm new to VBA and still struggling with this sadly :( are you able to write an example? What format should the report name be? Thanks again

Comment: What I gave you is an example. You need to substitute your actual object names and criteria for everything with <>. The report name is whatever you name it.